# Examples of exact couples of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Exact couples are really important when defining spectral sequences. However, I have never really seen a simple non-trivial example of two exact couples of abelian group with a morphism between them. Are there simple interesting examples? An example that would be interesting is a morphism such that the kernel is not an exact couple.